# How to make OctoPrint API calls from an android app to controll devices with similar functionality to 3D printers?

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley, octoprint

I've created an Android app (written in java) to control the functions of a Kinetic Sand Table, which is based with its functionality on OctoPrint with exclusion of the z axis.

To make sure everything would work prior to hooking up the the SandTable, I decided to start off with attaching the 3D printer. That didn't work because the printer I have is already hooked.

So change of plans, now I tried using the Virtual Printer option. and i'm running OctoPI

#### What is the problem?

my app is not making API calls!
I'm figuring, something wrong with how I'm trying to access the endpoints!

i'm recieving a "Timeout or no connection error occurred" at the app's launch.

I tried to hash map the headers

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//String url = "http://octopiaddress/api/job/start?apikey=mynoneglobalapikey";

    private static final String OctoPrint_IP = "octopiaddress";
    private static final String baseUrl = OctoPrint_IP + "/api";
    private static final String jobUrl = baseUrl + "/job";
    private static final String API_KEY = "mynoneglobalapikey";
    private final String TAG = "tag123";
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    Button playButton;
Spinner patternSpinner;
private static final String files = baseUrl + "/files/local" + API_KEY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set the theme to no title bar
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
        // set the content view for your activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button);

patternSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Api-Key", API_KEY);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(v -> startPrintJob());

        // The URL to retrieve the patterns from the OctoPrint API
        //String filesUrl = "http://octopiaddress/api/files/local?apikey=mynoneglobalapikey";
        // Make the HTTP request to retrieve the patterns from the OctoPrint API
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                files,
                null,
                response -> {
                    // Log the response received
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response received: " + response.toString());
                    // Parse the JSON response and add the patterns to the spinner
                    List<String> patternNames = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject pattern = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = pattern.getString("pattern");
                            patternNames.add(name);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // Creating adapter for spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, patternNames);
                    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // attaching data adapter to spinner
                    patternSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP request successful");

                },
                this::handleVolleyError

        );

        // Add the request to the Volley request queue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);

        // Set a listener for when a pattern is selected in the spinner
        patternSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedPatternName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Construct the JSON object to start the pattern
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonBody.put("name", selectedPatternName);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Log the JSON body being sent in the request
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending JSON body in the request: " + jsonBody);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // Not used in this example
            }
        });
}

    private void startPrintJob() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("command", "start");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, jobUrl, jsonObject,
                response -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Print started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), error -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to start print", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                return headers;
            }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }

    private void handleVolleyError(VolleyError error) {
        String message;
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            message = "Timeout or no connection error occurred";
        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            message = "Authentication error occurred";
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            message = "Server error occurred";
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            message = "Network error occurred";
        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            message = "JSON parse error occurred";
        } else {
            message = "Unknown error occurred";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Outputting what the actual `VolleyError` is rather than your message would be useful.